# Jquery : specify an id of an input:checkbox element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, input

I have this little sample if jquery code, but I want to make it more specific for one of two different inputs of my HTML page.

```
  <script>
  // check only one box at time
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input:checkbox').click(function() {
          $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
      });
  });
  </script>
```

And these are the two concerned inputs :

```
<div id="reponses-section" class="form-check">
    <c:forEach items="${question.reponses}" var="reponse">
        <input id="${reponse.id}" name="id-reponse" value="${reponse.id}"
                type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
        <h5>${reponse.texte}</h5>
    </c:forEach>
</div> 

<div id="theme-btn" class="pull-right">
    <label class="switch">
        <input id="changeThemeBtn" type="checkbox" onclick="getTheme(this);" value="dark">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Is it possible to specify an id for the js sample of code, and if yes what is the syntax to use ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: So you are recreating radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery selects items using CSS selector syntax, so ID would just be `#yourTargetId`.

Comment: // check only one box at time
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-check-input input:checkbox').click(function() {
   $('.form-check-input input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
 });

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use this method. You can change the `data-id` name with whatever you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[data-id="checkbox1"]').click(function() {
        $('input[data-id="checkbox1"]').prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input data-id="checkbox1" id="${reponse.id}" name="id-reponse" value="${reponse.id}" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">

<input data-id="checkbox2" id="changeThemeBtn" type="checkbox" onclick="getTheme(this);" value="dark">
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore... This sample of code is supposed to allow one checkbox checked at a time... But now i cannot check anyone...

Comment: No @jozinho22 It still works, but you shouldn't use .not(this) and .prop("checked", false). Because if you use those, you cannot check these. And now I edited my post, please run the code snippet.